# Inserir valor selecionado em array/drop down em banco de dados

Tags: php, joomla

Seguinte: Uso o **RSForm!** e ao invés de usar a funcionalidade *Mapping* que ele oferece, faço o script de *Update* (caso o usuário logado já tenha cadastro) e Insert (caso não tenha). Esse script é inserido na parte `"Script called on form process"`. Aqui faço os testes e atualizo ou insiro os dados no banco.
Meu problema está no seguinte: tenho 1 drop down no formulário cujos items são atribuídos através de um array, conforme código abaixo:

```
*//<code>
$items = array('','1|Solteiro','2|Casado','3|Marital','4|Desquitado','5|Divorciado','6|Viúvo','7|Outros');
$db = JFactory::getDbo();
$idUsuarioLogado = JFactory::getUser()->id;
$db->setQuery("SELECT estado_civil FROM minha_tabela WHERE id_usuario = $idUsuarioLogado");
$result = $db->loadObject();

foreach ($items as $chave => $item) {
  if($result->estado_civil == $chave){
    $items[$chave] = $item."[c]";
  }else{
    $items[$chave] = $item;
  }
}
$items = implode("\n", $items);
return $items;
//</code>*
```

Quando o usuário está logado e já possui cadastro, ele trás os dados do banco certinho e preenche o drop down. Quando não está, ele preenche com a lista para que o usuário escolha.

O problema é: como eu insiro no banco o valor selecionado no drop down?

Porque se eu pegar apenas assim: `$estado_civil  = $_POST['form']['estadocivil'];`
Ele me retorna um array e não insere nada no banco de dados.

Alguém tem uma luz?

PS: Quando uso a funcionalidade *Mapping* e faço um *INSERT*, ele insere normalmente os dados do drop down no banco. Não uso o *Mapping* porque preciso testar se vou dar um *UPDATE* ou um *INSERT* no banco. E não descobri se é possível fazer esse teste usando essa funcionalidade.

Comment: Por acaso essa array tem os valores como array([0] = > 1 [1] => solteiro)?

Comment: Sim, o array fica dessa forma.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tudo indica que o RSForm! transforma o valor do select numa array onde o primeiro elemento é o código da opção e o segundo é a opção em si. Neste caso, basta pegar a informação que você deseja em:

```
$_POST['form']['estadocivil'][1]
```

Supondo que "1" seja o índice correspondente ao valor.

Comment: Muito obrigada! Realmente o RSForm! faz isso mesmo.. Resolveu o meu problema!

Comment: @Fernanda bemvinda ao Stackoverflow! Se esta resposta resolveu o seu problema pode também marcar como aceite.